# Django Rest Framework - add a field from database to CreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to save the model, but one field must get data from db.

Better to show code to illustrate my intentions

```
class LoyaltyUserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = LoyaltyUser
        fields = [
            'name',
            'last_name',
            'gender',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'birth_date',
            'account'
        ]

    def get_account(self, obj):
        return Account.objects.get(pk=self.context['request'].user.pk)
```

data that I Send

```
{"name": "Petr1", "last_name": "Petrov", "gender": "male", "email": "email", "phone": "123", "birth_date": "2018-12-12"}
```

The problem is that when I try to save it with CreateAPI I get 500 error with

```
IntegrityError at /api/create_user
NOT NULL constraint failed: core_loyaltyuser.account_id
```

View

```
class LoyaltyUserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = LoyaltyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoyaltyUserCreateSerializer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `perform_create` method of CreateAPIView:

```
class LoyaltyUserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
  queryset = LoyaltyUser.objects.all()
  serializer_class = LoyaltyUserCreateSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(account_id=self.request.user.pk) # updated after feedback
```

See [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods)

Also, you don't need to define `account` as `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` in your serializer, it is used for read-only purpose. (For example, you need to do send some extra data in response instead of only the id of `account`)

Add it to read_only_fields instead:

```
class LoyaltyUserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LoyaltyUser
        fields = (
            'name',
            'last_name',
            'gender',
            'email',
            'phone',
            'birth_date',
            'account'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('account',)
```

Comment: that's works great, except that in save method I need to pass account_id=self.request.user.pk. Thanks, anyway!